# How to restrict calendar date selection between today -3 previous days

Tags: sharepoint

How to restrict calendar date selection between today -3 previous days. I'm looking this for SharePoint online.

Example: today 12 August 2020, calendar selection should only permit user to select dates 12, 11, 10 & 9 August 2020 beyond these dates it should give a error message to select date with in last 3days only.

I'm trying with Column validation but no luck. any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use list validation for this. GO to List settings->Validation settings

```
=AND([Start Time]<TODAY(),[Start Time]>TODAY()-3,[End Time]<TODAY(),[End Time]>TODAY()-3)
```